# Why didn't Lucius tell Bruce Wayne about Coleman Reese?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight

About a third of the way through *The Dark Knight* one of the financial contractors for Wayne Enterprises discovers the identity of Batman due to "irregularities" in the finances.

When Lucius is confronted by it he 'manages the situation' by embarrassing Reese and belittling his blackmail idea, but, doesn't tell Bruce Wayne about it at all in the next scene even though Lucius *does* still reference his conversation with Reece when asking Bruce about R&D being reassigned (to a government telecom contract).

Shouldn't Lucius have also thought it important to mention that someone has discovered Batman's identity? Was this a lack of judgement on Lucius' part?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reese is, for lack of a better word, a twerp. He is not a particularly big player or a threat to anyone.

In the conversation with Lucius, it was painfully obvious that he was playing a game outside of his league, and Lucius' witty remark made him immediately withdraw.

It is reasonable for Lucius to assume the threat had been dealt with.

Secondly, how do you know for certain that Lucius never informed Bruce? Just because it was not on camera does not mean that it did not happen; just that it was not relevant for the rest of the plot (since Reese never follows up).

Thirdly, there is also no evidence that Reese's information would be dangerous. They may have already prepared an explanation for the inconsistencies.

Given how careful and methodical Bruce is about his logistics in Batman Begins (e.g. needlessly ordering industrial quantities of a mask through shell corporations), it is reasonable to assume that he would be well covered even if the inconsistencies were brought to light.

Comment: It's probably logical to assume that Lucius cannot be the only one in the company who's at least partially privy to Bruce's secret.  Maybe not all the people that would be required to manufacture all of that high tech Bat-gear are in on the Bruce Wayne/Batman connection, but they must be aware at least on some level that they are, in fact, working for the Batman.  You don't just make a thousand bat-shaped shuriken and *not* figure out who's using them.  This may be the first film in the franchise to acknowledge that.  I'm guessing there's some sort of strict NDA involved...

Comment: "since Reese never follows up"—until later, when he starts to reveal it to the press, after which the Joker tries to get people to kill him by threatening to blow up a hospital.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Lucius is put on some sort of graveyard shift because nobody likes him and they want to not deal with him, so it's reasonable to assume no one is keeping active tabs on him and his activities. Wayne Enterprises also has a _ton_ of old R&D from potential contracts, and it is doubtful that these are obviously related to and could be the only possible source of the bat gadgets, or that anyone except Lucius has a comprehensive knowledge of what the R&D archives contain.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon You make a very valid point that I forgot about. I guess the second and third option (having told Bruce off screen and having prepared plausible deniability) is the most likely then.

Comment: Lucius may be the only one with the *whole* picture (other than Alfred probably), but Lucius is just one guy - it would take a team of hundreds or even thousands of people to develop some of those gadgets.  Sure, some of them probably think it's just a regular defense contract of some sort, but it's hard to pretend that's what it is when you're making batarangs, pointy-eared masks that cover only the top half of your face, suits of armor with a big old bat-symbol emblazoned on the chest, etc.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Most major technologies Lucius showcases are existing (genuine) contracts which either never came to fruition or a prototype was at least kept in the R&D archives. There's no indication that the bat-branded things are being outsourced. And even if it were, given the international reach of Wayne Enterprises, it would be easy enough to outsource it overseas where Batman is not known.